# vcan0 causing ip conflict in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, socketcan

I've just created a ubuntu 16.10 machine and tried to create a vcan network:

```
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
```

As soon as I enter this though I lose my internet connection.

```
ping www.google.com
```

Never returns.  I'm not even bringing the vcan0 interface up.  Just loading the standard vcan module
Any thoughts where to even start to debug?

Comment: More information.  My network is as such  CableModem(10.0.0.1)-->Router(192.168.1.1)-->Ubuntu Computer(192.168.1.167).  After I add the vcan device I can still ping the router and other computers (laptop) on the 192.168.1.x network.  Just can't get through to the internet,  or perhaps the return route can't get back?

Comment: If I sudo add....sudo del....sudo add...sudo del....Then my network seems to be okay.  Not sure what is going on